# TypeORM - appending new items to array-type column (Postgres)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

Postgres supports array type columns, and exposes methods for working with those arrays (like `array_append`). I'm wondering if TypeORM allows using those methods somehow.

In case it's not supported, what do you think the best way to append items to PG array? Doing something like get-and-set? (a transaction of getting the value, creating the new new array with js, and updating the value in the DB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use native Postgres methods like `array_append` if you use the TypeORM Query Builder.

Example below:

```js
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder()
  .update(User)
  .set({
    yourArrayColumn: () => `array_append("yourArrayColumn", 1)`
  })
  .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
  .execute();
```

More about using TypeORM Query Builder for updates:
https://typeorm.io/update-query-builder